# SSH to arbitrary user

Tags: linux, openssh, sshd

I am working on a project where I run some isolated applications in containers.
I want to give certain people access to specific containers over SSH.
Until now I have been able to get it working by adding the following to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
Match User tester
    ForceCommand docker exec -it mycontainer /bin/sh
    AuthorizedKeysFile /opt/tester_keys
```

This works as long as the user `tester` exists on the host OS and has permission to execute `docker exec`.
If I then a `Match User` entry for a non-existing user on the Host OS, then it does not work:

```
Match User nottester
    ForceCommand docker exec -it nottestercontainer /bin/sh
    AuthorizedKeysFile /opt/nottester_keys
```

In the logs I get `Invalid user nottester from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 35703`.

Is there a way to the `sshd` to authenicate just using the authorized keys?

Host OS is Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Server

In the end I would prefer the following:

1. A user connects as `nottester` to the server
2. Access is validated using the provided `AuthorizedKeysFile`
3. If access is granted the `ForceCommand` is executed as user `container_admin`, who has permission to do this

Can this be done with `sshd` or do I need something else to handle this?

Comment: It might help someone to know what OS you're targeting.  FreeBSD has a [`pam_jail`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=pam_jail) module that sounds like it does what you want, but I don't know whether Linux `pam` offers a comparable module.  (edit:) [This module](https://github.com/flant/pam_docker) is experimental, but claims to be close to what you're after, or perhaps at least a partial solution.

Comment: Did you try "Match User tester15" ? In other words, "Match User X" when connecting with username X, with X not existing on host OS ? I think that will work !! Worth a Quick Check !!

Comment: ct thisSorry for the missing information. It is supposed to work on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. I have updated the initial question to refle

Comment: I want to re-highlight **tester15** in your Issue "In the logs I get Invalid user **tester15** from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 34948." which mismatches **nottester** in your config "Match User **nottester**" ; Hence I gave the "suggestion" earlier !

Comment: My mistake. Put in the wrong log entry as I tried with multiple different usernames

Answer (score 1):

The ssh service requires a user account known to its system for authentication purposes. This isn't negotiable: the target account *must* exist on the remote system. In your example this is `nottester`.

Now let's look again at your requirements:

> 1. A user connects as nottester to the server
> 2. Access is validated using the provided AuthorizedKeysFile
> 3. If access is granted the ForceCommand is executed as user container_admin

On the client side, specifiy `nottester` as the user account to connect:

```
ssh nottester@remoteserver ...
```

Or add it to the client `~/.ssh/ssh_config` configuration/preferences file:

```
Host remoteserver
    User notttester
    IdentityFile my_privatekey_for_remoteserver_ed25519.key
```

so that you don't need to remember the user account:

```
ssh remoteserver
```

On the server side it looks like you already have it set up to allow connections from this user accout and force a command.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The client side is quite easy to handle. But it is the server side that is causing some issues, as it does not log in due to the user not existing in the server and technically it should not

Comment: Please add that and all other useful detail to your question! We can neither read your mind nor look over your shoulder to see what you can see. You must tell us

Comment: I've answered your comment in my first sentence: the target account _must_ exist on the remote system. This isn't negotiable